# Is it possible to have method only accessible after certain conditions are met?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm trying to make a method, MethodA, only accessible when bool, executable, is true. Otherwise an other method, MethodB, is accessible. For example:

```cs
private bool executable = true;

public int MethodA(); <-- // Is accessible from outside of the class because executable is true

public string MethodB() <-- // Is not accessible because executable is true
```

The main reason I'm trying to do this is because the 2 methods return 2 different types. So my question is, is this even possible?

Comment: [Conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) can be an answer.

Comment: How do you use those methods/What is the context you use this in?

Comment: This sounds like the makings of an XY Problem.  What's the overall goal here?  That is, what underlying problem are you trying to solve by attempting to do this?

Comment: if the condition is known at compile time: yes, with preprocessor statements, else: no

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is probably possible using type safety, but it's hard to provide an answer without seeing how you expect the methods to be called.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "accessible". If you mean "will lead to compiler error if it isn't available", then no. If you mean "will throw an exception if not available", then sure, just write the necessary if-statements inside the methods. You can also make the methods available through an intermediary that is only available in the right state.

Comment: Sorry about the late response, internet went out. `newClass.MethodA()` I indeed meant compiler error. But after thinking about it myself it's impossible for C# to know if a variable is going to be true or false before even running it. I'll be going with an object return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #1

You may be able to get what you want using Polymorphism and Generics. This would also allow you to add additional method strategies if needed.

```
public interface IMethodStrategy<out T>
{
    T DoSomething();
}

public class MethodOneStrategy : IMethodStrategy<string>
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return "This strategy returns a string";
    }
}

public class MethodTwoStrategy : IMethodStrategy<int>
{
    public int DoSomething()
    {
        return 100; // this strategy returns an int
    }
}

// And you would use it like so...
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool executable = true; 
    object result = null;
    if (executable)
    {
        MethodOneStrategy methodA = new MethodOneStrategy();
        result = methodA.DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        MethodTwoStrategy methodB = new MethodTwoStrategy();
        result = methodB.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Option #2

Another option could be a simple proxy method to wrap the worker methods.

```
// proxy class to wrap actual method call with proxy call
public class MethodProxy
{
    public object DoMethodWork(bool executable)
    {
        if (executable)
        {
            return MethodA();
        }
        else
        {
            return MethodB();
        }
    }

    private int MethodA()
    {
        return 100; // returns int type
    }

    private string MethodB()
    {
        return "this method returns a string";
    }
}

// used like so
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var methodProxy = new MethodProxy();
    object result = methodProxy.DoMethodWork(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) for this.

```
#if RELEASE

public string MethodB() ...

#endif
```

Although I have my doubts about whether you need this or not.  Your rationale doesn't make much sense.

You can use different [Build Configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2019) to manage your conditional compile symbols.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(executable)
 MethodA();
else
 MethodB();
```

OR

```
if(executable)
 MethodA();

MethodB();
```

Comment: This does not change the accessibility of the class methods

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure what you are trying to do but this could be one way, probably not the most efficient way but could work depending on what you are trying to do?

```
public int MethodA(executable)
{
    if(executable = true)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

public String MethodB(executable)
{
    if(executable = false)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        String error = "MethodB cannot be used right now";
        return error;
    }
}
```